# How to rotate the 3D manipulator to match object's rotation?

Tags: 3d-view, transforms

I'm having a problem with the 3D manipulator in Blender when I look at an object from the top view (<kbd>Numpad 7</kbd>).

The 3D manipulator is not following the rotation of the object, instead the red and green arrows are going diagonally.

Please see attached picture. Can I change it so that arrows match the object's rotation?

[image: rotated manipulator widget in 3D view]

Comment: What is your transformation orientation?

Comment: I'm not sure, where can I see it? I don't have it under View tab? I have Blender 2.74 Thanks!

Comment: Oh I found it! It's set to Edge

Comment: Ok I changed it to Global and it works nice :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure your Transform Orientation is set to Global

[image]